# How to add page in back office module in prestashop

Tags: php, smarty, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

how to create new page in module back office in prestashop 1.6
and how to pass url of that new page into anchor tag.
any help appreciated.

```
<a id="desc-tag-new" class="list-toolbar-btn" href="#"></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a manual and a programmatic way.

If the module is for private use, you can simply go to **Administration** > **Menus** and create a new menu page by associating it with a module, class and parent.

If you want to distribute the module, you should opt for the programmatic way. You have to create an AdminController extending the `ModuleAdminController` class and put it in `/controllers/admin/`. In your module's installation method, you should create and save/add a new `Tab` (which extends `ObjectModel`, hence the save/add ambiguity depending on your PrestaShop version). You should then set the properties of the new `Tab` object as you would from **Administration** > **Menus**.

Keep in mind that in PrestaShop, a new Menu page is associated with a specific `ObjectModel` subclass.